# Likelihood that observed relative frequencies match a probability distribution

Tags: distributions, likelihood-ratio, discrete-data, frequency

For this question, please assume probability distributions are discrete.

If I have $N$ data points ($x_1, x_2, ..., x_N$), and I want to know the likelihood that these samples came from a discrete probability distribution, $f(x)$, I can use:

$$P(x_1,x_2,...,x_n|f(x)) = \prod_{i=1}^N f(x_i) $$

---

If instead I have an observed relative frequency distribution (a normalized histogram), but I absolutely do not know the total number of samples, how would I go about this problem?

Say, I am given some "observed" histogram that tells me that the relative frequencies for $0$ and $1$ were $0.3$ and $0.7$, respectively. But for some reason, I am unable to determine the number of samples/counts that went into this measurement. It could have been 3 zeros and 7 ones, or 363 zeros and 847 ones. We just don't know!

What is the likelihood that this data was sampled from $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(0.4)$?

It is my intuition that, it is probably impossible to assign a "likelihood" here (but I would be happy to be wrong about this).

---

But what about "relative likelihood". Say, I have many possible model distributions. Even if I can't tell in an absolute sense what the likelihood is that my observed histogram matches a specific distribution, it should be possible to determine some metric that indicates a preference for one distribution over another (for example, a likelihood ratio).

For instance, the example used above, it is obvious that $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(0.001)$ is less likely to be the underlying distribution for the data compared to $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(0.4)$ (even without knowing the total number of counts).

So, what is the appropriate way to compare two or more distributions in this context where you only have observed relative frequencies?

Comment: It's not quite what you're asking, but potentially relevant: while $n$ is definitely part of the likelihood, and indeed it matters, not knowing the exact $n$ is not the end of the story. We can use the proportions to
get a lower bound on the possible $n$. For example consider that
we observe $343:852$ instead, but we don't record the actual
numbers, just a proportion: $343/(343+852)$ rounded off to $0.2870$, say.
Note that $343$ and $852$ are fortuitously relatively prime but nevertheless
because we have rounded the proportion we cannot recover those numbers. ...ctd

Comment: ctd... While $0.2870$ is not consistent with very small counts, it is consistent
with smaller count-pairs than the ones that generated it, such as $31:77$
or $64:159$. The smallest of these may sometimes still allow for useful "worst case consistent with the proportions" inference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 successes out of 10 trials, then there is scant evidence against a success probability of $0.5,$ as shown by the large P-value in `binom.test` below. (using R):

```
binom.test(7, 10, .5)
    Exact binomial test

data:  7 and 10
number of successes = 7, number of trials = 10, 
 p-value = 0.3438
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3475471 0.9332605
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                   0.7
```

However, if it's 847 successes in 1210 trials,
you have strong evidence against a success probability of $0.5:$

```
binom.test(847, 1210, .5)$p.val
[1] 5.031361e-45
```

So, you really do need to use counts instead of
proportions.

---

However, if you have several digits of accuracy
for the proportions, you may *sometimes* be able to guess the minimum number of trials consistent
with these proportions.

For a contrived example, if proportions are $0.2246, 0.2681, 0.1232, 0.3841,$ then it seems unlikely $n$ could have
been smaller than $n = 138.$

```
 x = c(31, 37, 17, 53) 
 sum(x)
 [1] 138
 pp = round(x/138, 4); pp
 [1] 0.2246 0.2681 0.1232 0.3841
```

If I explored correctly, 138 is the smallest
"candidate" sample size that gives "almost integer counts".

```
pp*138
[1] 30.9948 36.9978 17.0016 53.0058
```

So, it seems fair to guess that the counts
may have been $31, 37, 17, 53$ out of $138.$

```
x = c(31, 37, 17, 53) 
sum(x)
[1] 138
round(x/138, 4)
[1] 0.2246 0.2681 0.1232 0.3841
```

*Note:* Editors of reputable journals ordinarily require explicit statements of
sample size for all studies reported.
Managers of research groups in companies and agencies should make the same requirement for internal reports.